# Достать с БД по нажатию списка бокового меню

Tags: java, android, sqlite, arraylist

Добрый вечер, господа профессионалы! Обрисовываю мою ситуацию: мне нужно, чтобы по нажатию бокового меню менялся текст на экране. Фрагмент один, соответственно. Текст находится в БД. По сути мне нужно знать какой элемент бокового меню под каким id, и потом просто достать элемент с БД по этому id. Но проблема в том, что я не понимаю как именно это сделать. Нормальных примеров найти не получается. Хотя уверен, что реализовать это не так долго. Может подскажете как сделать или что почитать, потому что башка уже кипит, а мысли запутались. Заранее всех благодарю за помощь! Вот мой код:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView myDrawerList;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle myDrawerToggle;

// navigation drawer title
private CharSequence myDrawerTitle;
// used to store app title
private CharSequence myTitle;

private String [] viewsNames;

@Override
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Инициализируем наш класс-обёртку
    DatabaseHelper dbh = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    // База нам нужна для записи и чтения
    SQLiteDatabase sqdb = dbh.getWritableDatabase();

    // закрываем соединения с базой данных
    sqdb.close();
    dbh.close();

    myTitle = getTitle();
    myDrawerTitle = getResources().getString(R.string.menu);        

    viewsNames = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.views_array);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    myDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);       

    myDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.drawer_list_item, viewsNames));

    android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    myDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.string.open_menu,
            R.string.close_menu
    ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(myTitle);
            // название в ActionBar при закрытом меню
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(myDrawerTitle);
            // название в ActionBar при открытом меню
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(myDrawerToggle);             

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // on first time display view for first nav item
        displayView(0);
    }

    myDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
}

private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(
            AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id
    ) {
        // display view for selected nav drawer item
        displayView(position);
    }
}

// Метод displayView(int position) получает в параметрах id нужного view,
// а далее блок switch определяет, каким именно фрагментом нужно заполнить FrameLayout.

private void displayView(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new FirstFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new FirstFragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new FirstFragment();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        myDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        myDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(viewsNames[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(myDrawerList);

    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}
```

DatabaseHelper.java

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private final Context fContext;
// имя базы данных
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "colorcat_database.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "cattable";

DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    // версия базы данных последняя цифра
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    fContext = context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ("
            + "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + "title TEXT"+ ");");

    // Добавляем записи в таблицу
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    // Получим файл из ресурсов
    Resources res = fContext.getResources();

    // Открываем xml-файл
    XmlResourceParser _xml = res.getXml(R.xml.cats_records);
    try {
        // Ищем конец документа
        int eventType = _xml.getEventType();
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            // Ищем теги record
            if ((eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG)
                    && (_xml.getName().equals("record"))) {
                // Тег Record найден, теперь получим его атрибуты и
                // вставляем в таблицу
                String title = _xml.getAttributeValue(0);
                values.put("title", title);
                db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
            }
            eventType = _xml.next();
        }
```

MyAdapter.java

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

ArrayList<SimpleObject> objects;
Context context;

public MyAdapter (Context context, ArrayList<SimpleObject> objects){
    this.context = context;
    this.objects = objects;
}

// кол-во элементов
@Override
public int getCount() {

    return objects.size();
}

// элемент по позиции
@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {

    return objects.get(i);
}

// id по позиции
@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {

    return i;
}

// пункт списка
@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    // используем созданные, но не используемые view
    if(view == null){
        view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, viewGroup, false);
    }

    SimpleObject object = objects.get(i);

    // заполняем View
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtLabel)).setText(object.getName());          

    return view;
}
}
```

SimpleObject.java

```
public class SimpleObject {
private int id;
private String name;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {

    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {

    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {

    this.name = name;
}
}
```

Comment: Вы привели **очень** много лишнего кода, не относящегося к проблеме. Оставьте только необходимое - у многих такое обилие кода напрочь отсекает желание вникать в суть проблемы. В частности, разметка тут вовсе ни к чему, как и модель данных, адаптер, пустой фрагмент и класс для работы с БД и большая часть кода активити, в т.ч. методы для меню.

Comment: А вообще у вас же есть список данных с id - вот оттуда и берите ID для запроса в БД....

Answer (score 1):

Не очень ясна ваша проблема. Возможно, вам надо просто в момент нажатия на элемент меню передать номер нажатого елемента `position` во фрагмент перед его отображением в качестве аргумента, используя `Bundle` и `setArguments(Bubdle args)`. Далее, уже во фрагменте, в onCreateView достать `position` из аргументов (`getArguments().getInt("key")`) и, используя это число делать запрос в БД. Так у вас при нажатии на элемент меню будет отображаться фрагмент с инфой из базы для ID 0, 1, 2, 3 etc из БД.

Comment: Но номер позиции не одно и тоже, что ID в БД. Позиции всегда в порядке возрастания от 0, ID имеет сквозную нумерацию и при удалениях-вставках в БД будет только возрастать. Таким образом, если удалить первый элемент, то ID=0 существовать не будет, а позиция будет.

Comment: @pavlofff, возможно я не верно выразил свою мысль. Как я понимаю, ТС хочет элементов в меню столько, сколько записей в таблице. И надо, конечно, не `ID` приравнивать к `position`, но порядковый номер записи в таблице, отсортированной по ключу). Либо вообще по клику из объекта данных этот ID брать... Просто ТС, как по мне, не очень ясно обрисовал задачу и проблему и сложно ответить что-то более конкретное.